# Chromium menus blackout on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: chromium

I tried both graphical install and sudo install via terminal.  I'm running Ubuntu single boot on a Dell computer.  No other operating systems are on this computer.  Firefox is the only browser I'm using right now.  But I would really like to use Chromium.  As I hover my mouse over a Chromium menu everything in the menu was black.  I uninstalled it.  Anyone else have this happen?

Comment: Did you enable any flags in `chrome://flags`? What kind of a system are you using (amd, intel, nvidia, etc.)?

Comment: I am using an Intel Pentium processor 64 bit.  Once I installed Chromium I did not adjust any settings but I am not sure if flags were enabled on their own.  I did cut and paste the entire text from the terminal and saved it as a file.